# apt --fix-broken install

Tags: dependencies, tree

I am new to this.
Just got this message below and I cant figure out how to fix it

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libasound2 : Depends: libasound2-data (>= 1.1.8-1) but 1.1.3-5 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you tried the command `apt --fix-broken install`

Comment: You need to run the repair command as root: `sudo apt --fix-broken install`

Answer (score 5):

Easily Solved

From synaptic
- Filter by broken packages
- Select the broken ones
- downgrade to a stable version

Solved in this way